# Is creating a method considered an abstraction?

Tags: java, oop, abstraction

Let's say I have this method

```
void print(String msg){
 System.out.println(msg);
}
```

Since I created a method that prints, I don't have to know how it prints it, so is this considered an abstraction, or am I getting it all wrong?

Comment: Abstraction is when you have multiple interchangeable behaviors that are manipulated through a common interface using interfaces for example. So, if you had a IPrinter interface that multiple printers inherited with their own versions of print, that would be abstraction

Comment: Consider asking conceptual questions on software development on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: The term [abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(software_engineering)) refers to so many things in programming. A method is definitely a control abstraction since it's abstracting away the details of how printing is done. The `String` argument type would be a data abstraction. It's the generalization chosen that should accommodate most print use cases. You could also have `print(File file)` and `File` would also be an abstraction, but most likely at the wrong level of abstraction since it's probably a poor generalization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have created this method simply to hide the details of the underlying implementation, then it is encapsulation.

Your method is not abstract since it is a concrete implementation. You can only call it abstract when you define the signature in a interface or as an abstract method in a abstract class.

From java Tutorial:

> An abstract method is a method that is declared without an implementation (without braces, and followed by a semicolon), like this:
>
> `abstract void moveTo(double deltaX, double deltaY);`

Anything abstract can be existing in **thought or as an idea** but not having a physical or concrete existence. This came up when I looked up for the definition of abstract in google(https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=abstract%20definition).

Comment: I judt gave this as an example, what I want to determine is if creating a method and that method does complicated stuff, is that method an abstraction of what you want to do. Like, saving an employee to a database, you just have to call the saveEmployee() method

Comment: Your interface `IPrintable` doesn't make any sense. Why would you need to pass a String to a printable object? Perhaps you meant `IPrinter`?

Comment: @Dabet Wah, I simplified the explanation. If saveEmployee is a concrete implementation in a class, by definition it is not abstraction. But supposing you have a save operation that is defined on an Entity interface, and say Employee is a Entity. Then saving the Employee is a concrete implementation but saving the Entity is just an idea. Hence save operation qualifies to be an abstract operation.

Answer (score 0):

To a degree yes that is abstraction, anything using that doesn't need to know how it prints, just that it does. A better example would be using a repo.

```
interface UserRepo {
  public User getUserByUsername(final String username);
  public User updateUser(final User user);
}
```

You then code against the interface. For example if using spring dependency injection:

```
@Service
public class UserService {
  @Resource
  private UserRepo userRepo;

  public void updateUserEmail(final String username, final String newEmail) {
    final User user = userRepo.getUserByUsername(username);
    user.setEmail(newEmail);
    userRepo.updateUser(user);
  }
```

UserService doesn't know how the repo is getting the User just that it is, could be using a database, a flat file, or a webservice.

[Here is some more info on Abstraction, with pictures!](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2010/10/abstraction-in-java.html)

[Also this details the difference between abstraction and polymorphism](http://java67.blogspot.com/2015/05/difference-between-abstraction-and.html)